# Improve the EBS Backup Process Duration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am having couple of EBS Volumes and I have a cron which I would use to create snapshots from the volumes that are close to 1TB, the entire backup snapshot runs for nearly 5 to 6 hours. I understand that the single biggest factor which effects the delay is due to magnitude of the data changes from the previous backup(delta of data change). To prove that point, the snapshots are much faster if I try to take the snapshot again immediately after a successful backup.

Currently the Volumes are Magnetic, what are the ways to speed up the backup process. Will Changing those to SSD or Provisioned SSD help improve backup running time ?

Comment: Do you have any particular use-case that requires the snapshots to be faster? The snapshot only copies used/changed blocks, so doing an initial snapshot with less data will be faster and subsequent snapshots will be faster, too. How much data is on the 1TB volumes?

Comment: The volumes are usually 60% to 80% full. There are couple of times my daily snapshots run 24 hours. My concern is while backup process is on there would be a slight performance degradation- so I wanted to try what it takes to complete the backup process soon.